# Como hacer un reporte con Crystal Report y Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

necesito ayuda, estoy haciendo una conexión de una base de datos de SQL-Server 2012 y visual studio 2013 y quiero hacer unos reportes con Cristal report pero no se como empezar, ya que nunca he utilizado esa herramienta!

Answer (score 1):

primero necesitas descargarlo
[descargar](http://www.businessobjects.com/forms/crystalreports/viewer)

esto es un diseñador de reportes es muy fácil de utilizar, esto genera un reporte con un formato de forma local, lo llamas y puedes enviar la impresion directa usando el metodo `PrintToPrinter` del document

[Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirvio de mucho

Comment: de nada para eso estamos